# How to tokenize persian string and save that into txt file

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to tokenize the A.txt and save that into B.txt file
the string i'm trying to process is persian and i want to save that word by word in persian, this is my code

this is main.py

```
import LevelOne
import save_file
import nltk

original_data = " ".join(open("A.txt"))print('Processing')
save_file.saving(LevelOne.spliter(original_data))
print('Done')
```

this is LevelOne

```
import re 
import persian
import stop_word


def spliter(text):
    data = re.split(r'\W+',text)
    tokenized = [word for word in data if word not in 
    stop_word.stop_words]
    return tokenized
```

and this is saving part

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def saving(infile):
    outfile = open('B.txt', 'w')
    replacements = {'پ':'\u067e',
          'چ':'\u0686','ج':'\u062c', 'ح':'\u062d','خ':'\u062e', 
          'ه':'\u0647','ع':'\u0639', 'غ':'\u063a','ف':'\u0641',                                           
          'ق':'\u0642','ث':'\u062b', 'ص':'\u0635','ض':'\u0636', 
          'گ':'\u06af','ک':'\u06a9', 'م':'\u0645','ن':'\u0646', 
          'ت':'\u062a','ا':'\u0627', 'ل':'\u0644','ب':'\u0628', 
          'ي':'\u06cc','س':'\u0633', 'ش':'\u0634','و':'\u0648', 
          'ئ':'\u0626','د':'\u062f', 'ذ':'\u0630','ر':'\u0631', 
          'ز':'\u0632','ط':'\u0637', 'ظ':'\u0638','ژ':'\u0698', 
          'آ':'\u0622','ی':'\u064a', '؟':'\u061f'}
    data = " ".join(infile)
    print(data)
    for line in data:
        for src, target in replacements.items() :
            line = line.replace(src, target)
            outfile.write(line)
    outfile.close()
```

but when i open the B.text file , i See this

```
Ú Ù Ù¾Ø³Ø Ø³Ù Ø Ù Ø ÙˆØ ÛŒ Ú Ù Ø Ø Ø ØŸ
```

the original file look like this

```
گل پسر
سلام خوبی چه خبر؟
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. It seems you have a problem with Unicode... how is it related to the tokenization?

Comment: what do you expect to see in `B.txt`? how do you want to have each word separated by line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to replace Unicode characters.
In Python3 by default files are going to be saved in utf-8. 
However, in order to tokenize sentences and words, since NLTK doesn't support Persian, you may need to specify punctuations.

Here is an example of dummy tokenization without punctuations:

```
tokenized = [
    line.strip().split(' ')
    for line in open("A.txt")
]

with open('B.txt', "w") as f:
    for line in tokenized:
        for word in line:
            f.write(word+"\n")
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

A.txt:

```
گل پسر.
سلام، خوبی چه خبر؟
```

B.txt:

```
گل
پسر.

سلام،
خوبی
چه
خبر؟
```

But if you want to tokenize based on punctuations, here it is a simple solution (without NLTK or any extra library):

```
import re

original_text = " ".join([
    line.strip()
    for line in open("A.txt")
])

def sent_tokenizer(text):
    # sentence separators: ؟ . ! ?
    seperators = "؟.!?"
    pattern = r"[^{0}]+[{0}]".format(seperators)
    return re.findall(pattern, text)

def word_tokenizer(sent):
    seperators = "؟!.?,:;، \t"
    pattern = r"([^{0}]+)([{0}])".format(seperators)

    words_sep = re.findall(pattern, sent)
    words = [
        w
        for word, sep in words_sep
        for w in [word, sep]
        if w != " "
    ]
    return words

tokenized = [
    word_tokenizer(sent)
    for sent in sent_tokenizer(original_text)
]

with open('B.txt', "w") as f:
    for line in tokenized:
        for word in line:
            f.write(word + "\n")
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

B.txt:

```
گل
پسر
.

سلام
،
خوبی
چه
خبر
؟
```

Answer (score 2):

Most NLP libraries do not provide extensive support for Persian language processing. You can use the [hazm](https://github.com/roshan-research/hazm) library for Persian text processing. It provides functionalities like text normalization, tokenization, lemmatization, POS tagging, dependency parsing, embeddings, etc.

```
pip install hazm    

from hazm import word_tokenize

with open('A.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile, \
     open('B.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
   tokens = word_tokenize(infile.read())
   outfile.write('\n'.join(tokens))
```

A.txt:

```
گل پسر
سلام خوبی چه خبر؟
```

B.txt:

```
گل    
پسر    
سلام    
خوبی    
چه    
خبر    
؟
```